# Can i Disable\Enable inline respone buttons (preview pane buttons Reply/ReplyAll/Forward) for Outlook 2016?

Tags: c#, winapi, outlook, outlook-addin, ui-automation

I'm creating Outlook Addin.(C#)

How can I disable\endable buttons for Outlook 2016 (Reply/ReplyAll/Forward) at next image?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIzx3.png)

In Outlook 2013 background GUI was different. This buttons was a part of Toolbar, toolbar has handle and it allows to manipulate buttons enable\disable state using WinAPI.

But in Outlook 2016 toolbar was replaced to different controls.

Now it's:

panel (has handle)

grouping control (has no handle)

buttons (has no handle)

I found this information using UI Automation classes.

Please suggest any way how can i manipulate enable state of this buttons.

May be exist other direction where i can found solution.

Thanks for any responce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These buttons are not programmatically accessible. You can disable the "Forward" / "Reply" / etc.  action (`MailItem.Actions` collection), but the button will still be enabled, you will just get a prompt that the action is not available when you try to click the  button.

Comment: I see. Thank You Dmitry.

Comment: I thought that exist way to do it because for Outlook 2013 i can modify enable state.

Comment: How did you do in in Outlook 2013?

Comment: I found parent control of buttons, get HWND and use sendmessage winapi method to disable or enable them. But now they modified GUI and this method not working.

Comment: I don't think there is much you can do - if all you have is the automation/accessibility API, you can query whether a particular control is enabled, but you cannot change its state.

Comment: yes. but if control have handle, disable can be done using EnableWindow :) but any way for office 2016 no handle for buttons

Comment: These controls are just some pretty painting, they don't have HWNDs.